# error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int* nbGround = nullptr;
    int* nbTrades = nullptr;
    int* nbSpace = nullptr;
    
    nbGround = new int(24);
    nbTrades = new int(31);
    
    nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround; 
    
    cout << "Number of spaces for sale  : " << *nbSpace << endl;
    delete nbSpace;
    delete nbTrades;
    delete nbGround;
```

I would like to know why can't I add pointers? I would like `nbSpace` to be equal to 55 by using pointers, but I don't know how. I'm getting the error:

> incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'int *' from 'int'

Comment: Please paste your code again and format it as code. This is discussed in the FAQ and help is available on the edit screen.

Comment: what do you expect `nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround` to do?

Comment: do you want `nbSpace == 55` or do you want `nbSpace` to point to an `int` with value `55` ?

Comment: `nbSpace` is a pointer, but you attempt to assign an `int` to it.

Comment: the question is rather unclear, because your text does not match the code. `*nbTrades + *nbGround; ` is not adding pointers. It is adding two `int` (and then tries to assign the result to a pointer)

Comment: Adding two pointers isn't meaningful. What would you do with the sum of two addresses? Where would they point?

Comment: *"i would like nbSpace to be equal to 55 by [X]"* -- you could try simplifying your situation, in an attempt to discover which details are important. Have you tried making `nbSace` equal to 55 by the simplest method available, perhaps `nbSpace = 55;`?

Comment: I suspect you fundamentally misunderstand how pointers work. It is probably worth reading up on them.

Answer (score 3):

First, this:

```
*nbTrades + *nbGround
```

is not "adding pointers". Instead, two pointers are dereferenced and two `int`s are added.

Then, you try to assign the result (an `int`) to a pointer:

```
nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround;
```

That doesn't make sense. Probably you forgot another `*`:

```
*nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround;
```

This would dereference all three pointers, add two `int`s and assign the result to an `int`. I say "would", because `*nbSpace` is undefined, because it is just a pointer that does not point to a valid `int`.

I suppose this is just to practice, because there is no reason to use any pointer here. This is how your code can be made to work with minimal changes:

```
#include <iostream> 

int main() { 
    int* nbGround = new int(24);
    int* nbTrades = new int(31);
    int* nbSpace = new int(0);

    *nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround; 

    std::cout << "Number of spaces for sale  : " << *nbSpace << std::endl;
    delete nbSpace;
    delete nbTrades;
    delete nbGround;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [following outputs 55](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12fc1adaa1e1ad52)

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
int main() { 
int* nbGround = nullptr;
int* nbTrades = nullptr;
int nbSpace;

nbGround = new int(24);
nbTrades = new int(31);

nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround; 

cout << "Number of spaces for sale  : " << nbSpace << endl;
delete nbTrades;
delete nbGround;
}
```

It's unclear why you need pointers here at all, but the error you get is caused by trying to assign an int (the result of the addition) to an int *pointer*. If you make it a regular int (with some required modifications to the rest of the code), it runs fine. Once again, it doesn't look like you need pointers at all in this code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result in the integer being pointed by nbSpace like this:

```
// first allocate space for the result
nbSpace = new int(0);
*nbSpace = *nbTrades + *nbGround;
```

Otherwise, you're setting the value of the pointer to the sum of the integers. In other words, `nbSpace` refers to the pointer, and `*nbSpace` refers to the integer value being pointed by `nbSpace`.

Comment: That causes an access violation, because `nbSpace` was never allocated.

Comment: @AmiTavory you're right. I've corrected it.

Comment: Have you thought about why you initialized the allocated `int` to 0? It is one way, but did you consider `nbSpace = new int(*nbTrades + *nbGround);`?